# Expandable Mat-Table closing itself after update data source

Tags: angular, angular-material

I hope you can help me with this. I have a mat-table that receives data from an observable, each row has a component to render the details of each row. Inside there are mat-cards with different edit buttons that change the data with a mat-dialog. After closed the first mat-card updates itself mainly because it's the same object as the MatSource Type, inside this object there's an array of objects, the problem is when I update one of the objects the mat-table doesn't update. I tried calling the function to populate over with using trackBy, this approach make the table close because in the expandable table the object repeat itself two times and there's no way of identify the opened item (that I know), alternatively I use this.dataSource.data = [...resultList] with no luck, renderRows inside the populate function, changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() too. But I couldn't solve this problem. Is there a way that I'm not aware of? Thanks in advance

This is how I retrieve the data

```
getAllPersonsData() {
    // METODO LISTAR NECESITA UN FILTERBEAN
    const filterBean = {
      inicio: this.paginador.pageIndex * this.paginador.pageSize,
      maximo: this.paginador.pageSize, 
      direccion: this.matsort.direction,
      sort: this.matsort.active,
    } as FilterBean;

    this.personaControllerNg.listPersonaXClave(filterBean).subscribe({
      next: (personaBeanList: Array<PersonaBean>) => {
        this.dataSource.data = personaBeanList;
        // this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      }
    });
  }
```

This is the expandable table

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="tipDocUsuario">
    <th class="table-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Tipo de documento</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{getTipoDocumento(element.tipDocUsuario)}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="numDocUsuario">
    <th class="table-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>N° de documento </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.numDocUsuario}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="tipo">
    <th class="table-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Tipo de persona</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{mostrarTipoPersonasNombres(element.tipoPersonas)}}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="razon">
    <th class="table-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Razón social / Apellidos y nombres</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      {{element.apellidos === '' || !element.apellidos ? element.razonSocial : element.apellidos + ' ' + element.nombres}}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
      <div class="table-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
        <app-item-find-persona [selectedBean]="element" style="width: 100%;" (afterEdit)="refreshTable($event)">
        </app-item-find-persona>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay; let i = index" class="table-element-row"
    [class.table-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
    (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef=" let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="table-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [length]="paginador.pageLength" [pageSize]="paginador.pageSize"
  [pageSizeOptions]="paginador.pageSizeOptions" (page)="pageEvent($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

PersonaBean Object, this is the data that I'm trying to display:

```
export interface PersonaBean {
    properties: string;
    idpersona: number;
    estado: number;
    apellidos: string;
    nombres: string;
    cargo: string;
    filter: FilterBean;
    idtipoPrecio: number;
    flag: string;
    tipos: Array<any>;
    numDocUsuario: string;
    tipo: string;
    idlocalPersona: number;
    valid: ValidatorBean;
    giroNegocio: string;
    comision: number;
    correo: string;
    cuentas: Array<any>;
    localPersonas: Array<any>;
    tipDocUsuario: number;
    nacimiento: Date;
    sexo: string;
    razonSocial: string;
    creditoDolar: number;
    estadoSunat: string;
    nota: string;
    puntos: Array<any>;
    expanded: boolean ;
    estadoCredito: number;
    tipoPersonas: Array<any>;
    conductors: Array<any>;
    creditoSol: number;
    procedencia: string;
    idtipoTrabajador: number;
    condicionSunat: string;
    representantes: Array<any>;
    codTipoPersonas: Array<any>;

  }
```

Here are images of the data displayed.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kYcMYV62LLJ1JPg7LoPNJmpG_YLoX1DL?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a sample data too that you're trying to display